# How to run scripts and create html output on mobile

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, mobile, google-sheets-api

How can I run scripts on mobile phone? I have created an app with tons of code (sidebars, modals, forms, data manipulation by forms etc.) and I am not able to trigger any function. Also I can't see menu. I've created buttons by drawing and assigned scripts into them and if I click on 'em on PC it works as it should, but if I click it on mobile, it only selects and adds border and nothing is happening. I've also tried to create checkboxes and assign script into onEdit trigger (both - simple trigger and installed trigger) and still - on my PC it works perfect, but on mobile nothing happens. Is there any other way than convert my spreadsheet into web app (i.e. using something like appsheet) or create "regular" app by i.e. HTML/CSS/JavaScript/and some kind of serverside stuff and manipulate data through Sheets API? If there is any possiblilty to run those scripts on mobile in easier way, I'd love it.

Comment: *I've also tried to create checkboxes and assign script into onEdit trigger (both - simple trigger and installed trigger) and still - on my PC it works perfect, but on mobile nothing happens* Stackdriver Logs?

Comment: Voting to close this as duplicate. Ask  a new question with  [mcve] focusing only on *I've also tried to create checkboxes and assign script into onEdit trigger (both - simple trigger and installed trigger) and still - on my PC it works perfect, but on mobile nothing happens*